# Ubuntu autoinstall with Encryption not working

Tags: encryption, subiquity, autoinstall

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server 22.04 with auto-install mostly following [this article](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso/).  I can successfully get the cloud-init and use my user-data for the installation but I can't seem to get the encryption to work. Here's my user-data config.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  packages:
    - ubuntu-desktop
  snaps:
    - name: firefox
    - name: gnome-3-38-2004
    - name: gtk-common-themes
    - name: snap-store
    - name: snapd-desktop-integration
  identity:
    hostname: hostname
    password: [SHA-512 PASSWORD]
    username: username
  storage:
    layout:
        name: lvm
        password: [SHA-512 PASSWORD]
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of subiquity are you using?  The ability to give a password to the lvm layout was added in 23.04.2.  Can you try using the bare password instead of a password hash?  The examples I see use a bare password https://askubuntu.com/a/1464197/376778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a bare password, not a hash for the lvm password.
2. You have extra spaces in your lvm layout section. Each indent should be two spaces after the previous like this:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  packages:
    - ubuntu-desktop
  snaps:
    - name: firefox
    - name: gnome-3-38-2004
    - name: gtk-common-themes
    - name: snap-store
    - name: snapd-desktop-integration
  identity:
    hostname: hostname
    password: [SHA-512 PASSWORD]
    username: username
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      password: mypassword
```